# What is the difference between `a` and `a[:]`

Tags: python

Reading the Python 3.2 tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.2/tutorial/introduction.html), towards the end one of the examples is

```
a[:] = []
```

Is this equivalent to

```
a = []
```

? If it is, why did they write `a[:]` instead of `a`? If it isn't, what is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not equivalent. These two examples should get you to understand the difference.

Example 1:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a = b
>>> a[:] = []
>>> print b
[]
```

Example 2:

```
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a = b
>>> a = []
>>> print b
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is explained, as you would expect, right there were they use it:

> This means that the following slice returns a shallow copy of the list a

Answer (score 1):

The second line doesn't modify the list, it simply arranges for `a` to point to a new, empty, list. The first line modifies the list pointed at by a. Consider this sample seesion in the python interpreter:

```
>>> b=[1,2,3]
>>> a=b
>>> a[:]=[]
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
```

Both `a` and `b` point to the same list, so we can see that `a[:]=[]` empties the list and now both `a` and `b` point to the same empty list.